# Python. Import error with mysql.connector

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python, pyenv

I have some problems with mysql.connector.
Few days ago I install "pyenv" and install in virtual environment 3.8.1 python in my Debian server.

I have piece of code, which will provide me connection to mysql looks like:

```
import mysql.connector

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="{}".format(setings.DBUSER),
        passwd="{}".format(setings.DBPWD),
        auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
    )
```

and when I'm starting script

```
sudo python script_name.py
```

I got this message:

```
File "script_name.py", line 2, in <module>
     import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
```

(in my local computer it's work with pyenv and with pythhon 3.8.1)

But, when I manually import like:

```
pyton
>> import mysql.connector
>>
```

I have not see any errors messages.

Comment: oh, sorry, forgot about pip. Yes, I used pip for downloading mysql.connector. And I was download few version like (mysql-connector-python, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python-dd, mysql-connector-python-rf)

Comment: so, I guess problem with Pyenv.. becouse I have script which use sudo command. With Pyenv I'm installed 3.8.1 version, but when I'm use "sudo python" - python version automaticly downgrade to system version (2.7.4)